# How to remove all elements from a list except integer datatypes?

Tags: python, python-3.x, data-structures

I created a function that helps me to remove all other data types elements in the list except integer, but one error is that the function is unable to drop the last noninteger element.

Example 1:

```
l = [1, 2, 3, "a", "b", 4] 
required output is : l = [1, 2, 3, 4],
```

but function unable to drop / delete last non integer number i.e. 'b'  and return ,

```
l = [1, 2, 3,"b", 4].
```

Example 2:

```
l = ["A", 0, "Edabit", 1729, "Python", "1729"]
```

requited output : `[0, 1729 ]`

return output : `[0, 1729, '1729']`

Using remove:

```
def filter_list(l):
    for i in l:
        if type(i)!= int:
            l.remove(i)           
    return l
```

Using pop:

```
def filter_list(l):
    for i in l:
        if type(i)!= int:
            l.pop(l.index(i))           
    return l
```

Using del :

```
def filter_list(l):
    for i in l:
        if type(i)!= int:
            del l[i]           
    return l
```

Function Calling :

```
print(filter_list([1, 2, 3, "a", "b", 4]))
print(filter_list(["A", 0, "Edabit", 1729, "Python", "1729"]))
```

Output :

```
[1, 2, 3, 'b', 4]
[0, 1729, '1729']
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this out:

```
l = [1, 2, 3, "a", "b", 4]
only_integers = [x for x in l if not isinstance(x, str)]
```

Answer (score -2):

Just use a simple filter:

```
def filter_list(l):
    return [item for item in l if isinstance(item, int)]
```